# Implement text editing feature with custom keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, mobile-application

I have implemented the custom keyboard (with the help of Table->card->button widgets)  which looks like below, If the user press the button then I capture the text and just display it in to the screen.

[image]

By using this, user can enter the data but they cannot edit it.
How can I implement the text editing feature in this case ?

I have tried to use the TextField widget to fit in my case, it gives all the features including text editing. But it does not allow to use the custom keyboard.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: yes it works well for insert the text. but now I am trying to remove the text as well.

Comment: if you're trying to remove the selected text then you could use _insertText() with an empty string, if you want to remove the last character when pressing the remove button you could do something like _textController.text = _textController.text.substring(0, _textController.text.length-2). If the answer provided solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `readOnly` and `showCursor` properties of the `TextField` like this:

```
TextField(
  controller: _textController,
  readOnly: true,
  showCursor: true,
),
```

And then you could replace the selected text or insert a new text, like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _textController = TextEditingController();
}

_insertText(String textToInsert) {
  if (_textController.selection.start >= 0) {
    int newPosition = _textController.selection.start + textToInsert.length;
    _textController.text = _textController.text.replaceRange(
      _textController.selection.start,
      _textController.selection.end,
      textToInsert,
    );
    _textController.selection = TextSelection(
      baseOffset: newPosition,
      extentOffset: newPosition,
    );
  } else {
    _textController.text += textToInsert;
  }
}

Widget _buildRow(List<String> texts) {
  return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: texts
          .map((text) => RaisedButton(
              child: Text(text), onPressed: () => _insertText(text)))
          .toList());
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Calc")),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _textController,
            readOnly: true,
            showCursor: true,
          ),
        ),
        _buildRow(["1", "2", "3"]),
        _buildRow(["4", "5", "6"]),
        _buildRow(["7", "8", "9"]),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```